# Using get() to reference columns in quantmod arrays with R?

Tags: r, get, finance, quantmod, trading

I'm new to R, using the `quantmod()` package for a project. The following block of code works:

```
require(quantmod) 
stocks<-c("MMM", "MSFT", "BP")
for(i in 1:length(stocks)){
getSymbols(stocks[i], from= "2013-07-01")
s<-get(stocks[i])
dr<-dailyReturn(s)
print(paste(dr))
}
```

However, I need to reference specific columns to calculate some technical analysis indicators from the TTR package. For example:

```
open<-MMM$MMM.Open
RSI(open, n=14)
```

When I check:

```
identical(s, BP) #TRUE
```

And this works:

```
BP$BP.Open
```

However, this does not work:

```
s$s.Open #NULL
```

To provide adequate context, my goal is to go through a vector of stocks, check for a ]condition, then calculate some technical analysis and time series figures for that day and copy it into an ARFF file for use as training examples for a machine learning environment (Weka). Thanks.

Comment: `s$s.Open` doesn't work because the column names are based on the stock ticker of the data stored in the object, not based on the object name itself. If you think about it, there's no way for `getSymbols` to know the name of the object you assign its output to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's generally easier to use the extractor functions `Op` et al.  See `?OHLC.Transformations`.  Also, if you only have one symbol, you can use `auto.assign=FALSE` in your call to `getSymbols` to avoid the `get` call all together.

```
s <- getSymbols("BP", auto.assign=FALSE)
```

If you have multiple symbols, it's easier to store them in an environment and then loop over them with `eapply`:

```
e <- new.env()
getSymbols(stocks, env=e)
dr <- eapply(e, dailyReturn)
```

You can also apply TTR functions to each symbol this way.

```
rsi <- eapply(e, function(x) RSI(Op(x), n=14))
```

And you can use `do.call` with `cbind` to put them into a single object.

```
rsi_all <- do.call(cbind, rsi)
```

Comment: Joshua, this (all of it) would be perfect in the `getSymbols` help page. The current examples are all a bit artificial, just showing off the various ways to use the parameters. None of them use `eapply` which, the way you show it here, appears to go with `getSymbols` like wine and cheese :-)

Comment: @DarrenCook: if only some good Samaritan would provide a patch file... </subtle-hint> ;)